# Error: Too many values unpack (expected 2) when trying to loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a pair that is equal to 10 but cannot find it.

```
listOfIntegers = [8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1]
target = 10
noOfpairs = 0
def findPair(listOfIntegers, target):
    for i,j in range (len(listOfIntegers)),(len(listOfIntegers)):
        if listOfIntegers[i] + listOfIntegers[j+1] == target:
            print(listOfIntegers[i], "and", listOfIntegers[j], "is a pair")
            noOfpairs += 1
            print("number of pairs : ",noOfpairs)
            break
        
print(findPair(listOfIntegers, target))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your expected behaviour is, based on the way your code is written I assume you want to find the first pair and break...? But then why are you printing `"number of pairs"` if you break at the first pair...?

**I'm going to assume you want to find the total number of consecutive pairs in a list that add to 10.**

**Your code, and where it's wrong:**

1. `noOfpairs` is defined outside function `findPair`, but used inside.
2. Your for loop brackets are wrong - this is where you are getting your error.
3. You're breaking after finding the first pair (which might be what you want but it doesn't look like it)
4. You're running `print("number of pairs : ", noOfpairs)` inside the for loop (it's not a syntactical error but an inaccuracy - again, I don't get your expected behaviour)
5. You're printing the function (`print(findPair(listOfIntegers, target))`) as if it returned a value - it does not have a return statement therefore returns `None`. Run the function like this: `findPair(listOfIntegers, target)` or make it return `noOfpairs`.
6. In your for loop, why do you have 2 values `i` and `j` that both represent **the exact same value** for every iteration? It's not syntactically wrong but it makes no sense.

**Correct code:**

```
listOfIntegers = [8, 2, 5, 5, 1]
value_wanted = 10


def findPair(int_list, target):
    noOfpairs = 0
    for i in range(len(int_list) - 1):    # To stop index out of bounds error
        if int_list[i] + int_list[i + 1] == target:
            print(int_list[i], "and", int_list[i + 1], "is a pair")
            noOfpairs += 1
    print("number of pairs : ", noOfpairs)


findPair(listOfIntegers, value_wanted)
```

Comment: Presumably they're trying to solve the 2SUM problem and think they're iterating a 2D range, hence the independent i and j.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's the problem with this question - the expected behaviour is not given, so I had to make some sketchy assumptions from the print statements

Answer (score -1):

Passing two arguments to `range` does not return a list of pairs - the first argument in that case is interpreted as the number to start the range from. Example:

```py
print(list(range(3)))
print(list(range(1, 3)))
```

Output:

```py
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

For this task, a `while` loop is the simplest solution:

```py
listOfIntegers = [8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1]
target = 10
noOfpairs = 0
def findPair(iterable, pairSum):
    i = 0
    while i < len(iterable):
        j = i + 1
        if listOfIntegers[i] + listOfIntegers[j] == target:
            print(listOfIntegers[i], "and", listOfIntegers[j], "is a pair")
            noOfpairs += 1
            print("number of pairs:", noOfpairs)
            break
        
findPair(listOfIntegers, target)
```

Note how I changed the name of the arguments of the function - they should never be the same as the names of the variables passed to them, to avoid possible unexpected behaviour.